# Oracle 10g installation on windows 7 (64bit)

Tags: oracle

after installation of Oracle 10g on my windows 7 (64 bit) machine, I receive ORA-12560 error for TNS Protocol Adapter Error. With some google help I found out that there was no listener.ora file that I generated via Net Configuration Assistant. I restarted the pc but still no success and got same ORA-12560 error. I do not see any Oracle service in my Services.msc so I found out few other solutions like:

```
c:\>set oracle_sid=ORCL (worked fine)
c:\>net start oracleserviceORCL (The service name is invalid)
```

I found ORADIM utility help from google but the utility is not installed on my machine.

How to get this utility installed on my machine?
How to sort ORA-12560 error?
How to see Oracle Services on Windows Services section (services.msc)?

All I want to install oracle 10g with developer suite (as its done already but not working) and need to work on sqlplus, forms and reports.

Any help?

Haroon Rasheed

Comment: Did you check the registry? Open regedit and navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\your_oracle_home`

Comment: Have you created a database, or just installed the server software? Did dbca run as part of the installation?

Comment: no m8, i didn't create any database. i just installed oracle from installation cd using Next > Next > Finish ....

Comment: strange... HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software does not contain anything called oracle!

Comment: also, there is no dbca navigation under all programs > oracle devsuitehome_2 > configuration and migration tools

Comment: What exactly did you install - which CD and which options? It sounds like you just have the client installed, not the server. DO you want a local server running on your PC, or do you really want to connect to an existing database running somewhere else?

Comment: Yes I want a local server running. I have a CD containing two folders:
oracledevsuite_disk1
oracledevsuite_disk2

both downloaded from OTN and i made a DVD of them.

I am trying to install Oracle 10g suite (database and developer forms/reports etc) on my local machine to learn oracle)

can u guide pls

Comment: [Oracle Developer Suite](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/developer-suite/overview/index.html) has development tools, not a database. You'll need to [download](http://www.oracle.com/us/downloads/index.html) the database server software separately. Which versions depends on what you're dong. Or you can get a pre-built VM.

Comment: ohh! I thought it does contain a database. Ok, so just guide me what I do now? I download database server software from OTN and install straightaway with existing installation (of developer suite) or do I need to remove developer suite first and then install database and then install developer suite again?

Sorry for buzzing again and again but great to see your quick responses.

Comment: They're independent so I doubt you need to remove developer suite first. Check the version you have works with the database version though. Installing the DB software (or any software really!) is off-topic here, but there are plenty of guides for that, including Oracle's own documentation. Good luck,

Comment: Thanks Alex - I live in Karachi - Pakistan and tried stackoverflow for the first time and found it wonderful. Happy to see such nice peoples like you. appreciated

Comment: OK - i have successfully installed Oracle 11g express and tested via RUN SQL Command Line. Now, I installed Oracle Developer 10g suite and trying to connect it with 11g (express) database. I am sure there shouldn't be any problems but again it is saying the same ORA-12560!!! I tried:

c:\>set oracle_sid=ORCL (executed)
c:\>oradim -new -sid ORCL (service created)

I tried sqlplus using hr/hr@orcl and hr@orcl/hr even with xe but didn't work and giving me a different error with orcl:
ORA-12514: TNS: listener does not currently know of service requested in connect description
any ideas.....